# Adding meta tags on React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meta-tags

I'm trying to add dynamic meta-tags on every single page. But still can't see my meta-tags on my page source code. Do I need to put something in public/index.html... I'm not using server
I'm trying to add dynamic meta-tags on every single page. But still can't see my meta-tags on my page source code. Do I need to put something in public/index.html... I'm not using server
I'm trying to add dynamic meta-tags on every single page. But still can't see my meta-tags on my page source code. Do I need to put something in public/index.html... I'm not using server
Example:
Home page

```js
import {Helmet} from 'react-helmet';


export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {

        return (     
            <div> 
                <head>
                    <Helmet>
                        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                        <title>Home</title>
                        <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/" />
                        <meta name="description" content="Some description here" />
                    </Helmet>  
            </head>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>Website</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [React-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) for this as [react-meta-tags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-meta-tags) is outdated.

As the documentation example shows:

```
import React from "react";
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";

class Application extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
        <div className="application">
            <Helmet>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <title>My Title</title>
                <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/example" />
            </Helmet>
            ...
        </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Yes. I tried with React-helmet too but same - can't see meta tags on source code.

Comment: Did you try to use the Helmet without  wrapping in Fragment?

Comment: export default class Home extends Component {
    render() {

        return (     
            <> 
            <Helmet>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <title>Home</title>
                <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/" />
                <meta name="description" content="Some description" />
            </Helmet>

Comment: <> is still a fragment. 

Could you edit your question to have the file contents where you have the <head><head/> please?

Comment: What is in your public/index.html?

Comment: I edited question again and posted public/index.html

Comment: On any page to test the source code, I see the same index.html